# GVim for Remote Development

Tags: vim, ssh

I've adopted vim as my goto editor of choice over the past few weeks and have really enjoyed it. However for work I often must log into a remote server located in Asia (I'm on the eastern  US coastline) and I find using gvim (and really any GUI app) to be very slow. I have looked up some configurations to ssh which has made gvim operate at a better speed, but for the most part it still isn't fast enough. I was wondering if there are any other options I can use to speed up my connection and/or if Vim has remote deployment capability (ie. I edit files locally and they are synced to the Asia machine). Thanks a lot!

For sake of coverage here is my ssh config, it's added a nice boost.

```
Host abc.host.hosting.com
Compression Yes
ForwardX11 yes
Ciphers blowfish-cbc,arcfour
```

Comment: Consider `sshfs` and local `gvim`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25183709/1890567 you can also use the urls with `e`

Comment: Similar question with lots of tips: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605263/1427295

Answer (score 1):

Instead of controlling Vim through the laggy SSH connection, rather just fetch and update the file(s) themselves, and launch Vim locally.

Vim ships with a plugin called *netrw* which will allow you to do this.

```
vim scp://hostname/path/to/file
```

Will copy the file to you local machine and on save reupload it.

Take a look at netrw's documentation `:h netrw`